# Simple Authentication in .net WebPages

Tags: .net, authentication, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to authenticate through WebSecurity class.

I have a form and when a user submits this is called:

```
@{
    if(IsPost) {
        var username = Request["username"];
        var password = Request["password"];

        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(username, password, false);

        WebSecurity.Login(username, password);

        Response.Redirect("Default.cshtml");
    }

}
```

I already call:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Veidibok", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);
```

in my _appStart.cshtml file.

I get this error from the `CreateAccount()` call:

> [MembershipCreateUserException: The Provider encountered an unknown
>   error.]
>   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateAccount(String
>   userName, String password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +1312
>   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CreateAccount(String userName, String
>   password, Boolean requireConfirmationToken) +31
>   ASP._Page_Authentication_Register_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Users\Notandi\Documents\My Web
>   Sites\VeidiBok\Authentication\Register.cshtml:6
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1
>   executors) +68    System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>   +156    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +119

So anyone have any ideas? I'm really new at this, just trying out WebMatrix and .cshtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, this problem was a pain in my butt for the better part of today. I eventually had to check out the source code on Codeplex to get a better idea of what's happening ([http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae31d2579b9a#src%2fWebMatrix.WebData%2fSimpleMembershipProvider.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae31d2579b9a#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs))

It seems that the `CreateAccount` primarily creates account information in the membership table but before it does that the method will check for the presence of a user with the same userName in the User profile table specified in the Initialize statement `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`

You can either call the `CreateUser` before you call the `CreateAccount` method or call the convenience method `CreateUserAndAccount`.

Comment: wow - I thought this was supposed to be 'SimpleMembershipProvider'

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You have  create database Veidibok.sdf in DataBase workflow

Then

In Demo root folder create web.config file and add following code in connectionString area

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Veidibok" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Veidibok.sdf;" />
    </connectionStrings>
```